# Send multiple list parameters to a PL/SQL function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to call a function with a single parameter which contain a list delimited by a space.

```
('1 2 3')
```

Inside the function I've created a variable which converts this list to

```
('1,2,3')
```

I've bound this variable `var1(nvarchar(5000))` to in clause query inside function but is not passed. Was passed only one value 1 but multiple values like as `'1,2,3'` wasn't passed.

Ex1:

```
var1 := '1'
query syntax: col1 in (var1) -->> results are ok
```

Ex2:

```
var1 := '1,2,3'
query syntax: col1 in (var1) -->> doesn't output results
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

'1,2,3' is a string, not a set of numbers - there is no auto-parsing of text strings that happen to contain commas. It would be pretty disastrous if it did that.

[Comma-separated input](http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/comma-separated.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should to know that tis is dirty way and not advisable.

You probably doing something like this:

```
declare 
  i varchar2(200) default '1,2,3';
begin
select col1 into i from table_name where col1 in (i);
dbms_output.put_line(i);
end;
/
```

And you should get error like ORA-01403 , ORA-01722

If you do it like this:

```
    declare 
  i varchar2(200) default '1';
begin
  select col1 into i from table_name where col1 in (i);
dbms_output.put_line(i);
end;
/
```

There is no error
but you should to pass list as string not as variable like this using dynamic sql:

```
declare 
  i varchar2(200) default '1,2,3';
begin
execute immediate 'select col1 from table_name where col1 in ('||i||')' into i;
dbms_output.put_line(i);
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work.

```
query syntax: col1 in (select  xmlcast( column_value as number)  from xmltable('for $i in tokenize($str,",") return $i' passing  var1 as "str").
```